# Is there any way to convert GraphicsPath to single polygon in c#

Tags: c#, svg

SVGPATH converted to graphicPath, when i use g.FillPath then it's working properly but my requirement is g.FillPolygon, how can i convert?

I am using https://github.com/svg-net/SVG for SVG reading

```
if (obj is SvgPath o)
```

{
var graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();`
var start = PointF.Empty;
foreach (var segment in o.PathData)
{
start = segment.AddToPath(graphicsPath, start, o.PathData);
}

```
 g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, graphicsPath);  // it's Working properly

 g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, graphicsPath.PathPoints) // It's scre for some SVG Paths
```

}

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: There is no FillGraphicPath. I assume you mean [FillPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath) that takes a GraphicPath as second argument? If yes, doesn't GraphicPath give you with its [PathPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathpoints) the array you need to create a [FillPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)?

Comment: Note that a GraphicsPath can point data which are not simple straight lines (like curve segments, or figures/sub paths). If your particular SVG data contains such segments, then the points data in the _GraphicsPath_ cannot be simply drawn as a polygon. You gotta makes sure the SVG data only, and only, contains simple and straight line segments. In other words, the point type for _every_ point in your _graphicsPath_ must be `0x01` to be able to draw its points as a polygon.

Comment: You can convert it to a list of straight lines by `gp.Flatten`